# How to copy elements from XML that satisfy a given attribute condition?

Tags: xml, xslt

INPUT XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<breakfast_menu>
<food>
    <item name = "Belgian Waffles" price = "$5.95" calories = "650" />
    <item name = "Strawberry Belgian Waffles" price = "$7.95" calories = "900" />
</food>
</breakfast_menu>
```

So, basically I want to print the item that has price attribute greater than $6.

OUTPUT XML

```
<food>
    <item name = "Strawberry Belgian Waffles" price = "$7.95" calories = "900" />
</food>
```

I have to do it using XSL and I tried the same.

MY Attempt

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" />

<xsl:for-each select="breakfast_menu/food[@price &gt; 6]">
</xsl:for-each>


</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This isn't working . Please suggest the workaround. Thanks.

Comment: Is that your actual XML? If so, the `name = "Belgian Waffles" price = "$5.95" .... ` is just a single text node, and are not attributes. I would expect it to be `<item name="Belgian Waffles" price="$5.95"...></item>`.

Comment: The provided XML is not correct as I am assuming that you the "attributes" should be inside the "item" and then the Xpath should be like this food/item/@price then it should correctly work

Comment: That was a mistake.... I have edited the xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unluckily, I do not know the structure entire source. But if it contains only those tags, it would be enough to use this xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" />
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:for-each select='breakfast_menu/food/item[number(substring-after(@price,"$")) &gt; 6]'>
         <food>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
         </food>
      </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: It works Yuryi... Thanks... I'll need to understand it

Comment: number(substring-after(@price,"$")) typecasting the string value in number then check greater than 6.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you have the foreach incorrect - missing the "item"

`<xsl:for-each select="breakfast_menu/food[item/@price > 6]"/>`

This should be fine now